# Does ZooKeeper skip alerting the subscribers if multiple changes on a node?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

Is there a guarantee from ZooKeeper that if a node /a is updated multiple times, the client subscribing to the /a's data will receive all the updates and not only the latest one?

For example, a client A might try to update 1k/s times the node /a, will the client B receive all the 1k/s updates or only a percentage of it? I use the Java library to implement my clients

Comment: Can you copy/paste you code? Use you apache-curator?

Comment: I'm currently using the bare apache zookeeper connection. Would Curator handle the session expiration correctly?

Comment: If you can use curator: http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/persistent-ephemeral-node.html

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper offers guaranteed [linearizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) and [sequential consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_consistency).  The Apache ZooKeeper documentation on its [Consistency Guarantees](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkGuarantees) provides more detailed discussion of the consistency model.  Because ZooKeeper is designed to satisfy these properties, a client watcher receives notification of all updates, and multiple concurrent client watchers all will observe the same timeline of updates.  (Different clients connecting to different servers won't observe a different ordering of updates.)

ZooKeeper implements this by attaching a unique, monotonically increasing identifier to every update, called the [zxid](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_timeInZk).  The zxid values define the total ordering of write transactions to the system.

The ZooKeeper client keeps track of its last seen zxid.  If it accidentally connects to a ZooKeeper server that is lagging behind and doesn't have the latest zxid seen by the client, then the connection is aborted and the client will attempt to connect to another server that has the latest zxid.  After a successful connection, if the server has transactions with more recent zxids, then any client watches that match those transactions get triggered.

It's also important to keep in mind a few things that are not guaranteed.  It does not guarantee that all concurrent clients observe the exact same state at all times.  The documentation linked above about Consistency Guarantees has a warning note that explains this.

Additionally, what I described above only applies as long as the client process is constantly running.  If the process gets restarted, then the last seen zxid from the prior run would not be preserved.  The new process would establish a new connection and bootstrap itself by getting a new latest zxid from the server.  If there were updates applied while the process was down, then the new running process has no way of receiving notification of those changes.

Coding ZooKeeper clients to handle all failure modes correctly is tricky, so I echo the advice from the comments to consider using [Apache Curator](http://curator.apache.org/).